# Creating an auto-login script to website?

Tags: javascript, html, autologin

We have an intra-net website that requires me to enter login information every time and it's annoying.

I want to create some sort of automatic login for this website.
I tried creating a two-frame website, with one page being the login page and the other being my own html. In my html, I wanted to enter values to the textboxes in the other frame but got an "access denied" js error.

Any other idea?

(I know I can record a Macro, but unfortunately, can't install any third-party applications in the inner-network. I could also have used Robo-Form...).

Oh yeah, and it has to work on the worst browser ever, Internet Explorer 6...

Comment: Internet explorer 1 would have been worse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe local html file with form that mimic login form and with autosubmit (like `onload="form1.submit();"`?). Than you can run this file and it will autosubmitted and redirects you where you want to go (`form`'s action).

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that, didn't work. Apparently some unknown information is transferred in the view state or something. Or maybe I can't write: "http://somepage.aspx" as the form action and expect inputs to be passed correctly.

Comment: Use firefox+firebug to test your theory re view state, and compare the parameters both forms submit. Once they are the same, you can go back to ie6.

Comment: I tweaked, and tweaked, and copied-pasted the VIEWSTATE hidden input, and eventually it worked.

Answer (score -1):

A greasemonkey script might work.

Comment: He said it has to work in IE6, and he can't install third-party apps.